# Parsing CVS with unique formatting

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a PDF output of a list of categories, brands and products. However the listing is not searchable. The CSV conversation of the PDF leaves the output look like this:

"Cat 1"

"Brand 1"

"Product 1"

"Product 2"

"Brand 2"

"Product 3"

"Product 4"

"Cat 2"

For the most part, I can determine which is a category, brand or product. Brands don't have anything specific about them, but categories have (#/#) tag, products have a date on them.

I'm wondering how can I use ruby's CSV class to turn that into something like this, so that it's more searchable.

"Cat 1" "Brand 1" "Product 1"

"Cat 1" "Brand 1" "Product 2"

"Cat 1" "Brand 2" "Product 3"

"Cat 1" "Brand 2" "Product 4"

Answer (score 0):

you could

```
new_csv = 'Category,Brand,Product\n'
cat = ''
brand = ''
product = ''
regexp_cat = Regexp.new YOUR_REGEX_TO_IDENTIFY_TAG
regexp_prod = Regexp.new YOUR_REGEX_TO_IDENTIFY_DATE

File.foreach( 'file.txt' ) do |line|

  if line =~ regexp_cat
    cat = line
    # if the line is a category you'll want to move to the next without writing to "new_csv", until you find a product
    next

  elsif line =~ regexp_prod
    product = line

  else
    brand = line
    # same if the line is a brand you'll want to move to the next item until you find a product
    next
  end
  new_csv += "#{cat},#{brand},#{product}\n"

end
```

then you'll need to save "new_csv" to a file and that's it, now you can manipulate it with ruby's CSV lib.